# in a list, delete all the words which do not start with a capital letter

Tags: text-processing

Given a list of words (one per line) list1.txt I want to produce an output containing only the words which start with a capital letter. Any special option for grep?

Comment: nothing, because I do not know which is the right option for grep

Comment: does `list1.txt` file contain only words?

Comment: any line is exactly a word, (possibly containing symbols)

Comment: I mean I just want to delete the lines starting with a lowcase

Answer (score 4):

You can use the character class `[[:upper:]]` with `grep`:

```
grep '^[[:upper:]]' list1.txt
```